# Suppress a DateString

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I'm trying to suppress a formula field if it the date is greater for example 06/30/2013. 
I did a format field suppress formula 
{@DateString} > "06/30/2013" 
and still getting dates greater then 06/30/2013. 
Is there something that I'm missing that it might be because its a Date String.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your `{@DateString}` a string data type?

Comment: {@DateString} is a string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get this to work, you need to first convert the string into a date before doing any comparisons. So, `date({@DateString}) > #06/30/2013#` should get you what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the field and select `format field...`.  Select the `General` tab, then click the x+2 button to the right of the `Suppress` checkbox.  Enter the following text:

```
CurrentFieldValue>#06/30/2013#
```

Comment: Hi Craig, I did that and it seem to work but its suppressing dates lower for example 11/19/2012 that I need to show but its being suppress by the formula. Any idea what it might be. Thanks again for your help

Comment: What is the field's data type?

Comment: its a string field formula